# Setting the top value for a highcharts chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts chart where this is a snippet of the structure.

```
yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: y_max,
                    //...snip...//
        },
```

I set y_max to be the highest value in the chart. My goal is to have it so that point is at the top of the chart.

When y_max is less than or equal to 10,000, the chart scales so 10,000 is the top of the chart. When I go up to 10,002, the chart scales so 15,000 is the top of the chart (thus making the top point much lower than the top of the chart).

Is there any way to prevent this y axis increment jump so that the top of of the chart is really 10,002?

Update: here is a fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bvykw1eu/ 41 is the max, and it is showing a large space up to 50.

Comment: Have you tried `tickInterval`? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.tickInterval As it looks like the interval its using is 5,000, Here you can see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yhkrcque/24/ where original author had same problem as you: https://jsfiddle.net/yhkrcque/20/ <- original fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/asle/yhkrcque/20/ <- original fiddle. Oops.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want additional labels on the y-axis.

Comment: Then try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bvykw1eu/3/ Only problem is, setting it to 41 will make top value 44, if you set it to 40, then top value will be 40 and line will go outside of the graph. Looks like there is no real way of doing it.

Comment: Ah, but I can do label { step: 5 } and it will only show every 5th. That would resolve it.

Comment: See my edited comment.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the axis is layed out so that tick marks occur at the edges of the plot area. If the maximum data values are not near the end tick mark then there will be white space between the maximum data value and the edge of the plot area. If you set the yAxis endOnTick property to false then the axis is layed out so the maximum value occurs near the edge of the plot area. For example...

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    ...
    yAxis: {
        endOnTick: false,
        ....
    },
    ...
});
```

The YAxis also has a startOnTick property.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to prevent this:

- easy one: set `xAxis.endOnTick` to false and `xAxis.maxPadding` to 0, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bvykw1eu/4/ Downside of that solution is that `41` tick is not rendered (since it's not nice, round value)
- hard one: use `xAxis.tickPositioner` to calculate where ticks should be rendered. You can modify pre-calculates positions, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/bvykw1eu/5/

I suggest to use both solution and we get nice result:

```
yAxis: {
  floor: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  endOnTick: false,
  title: {
    text: 'Percentage'
  },
  tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
    var ticks = this.tickPositions,
        tLen = ticks.length;

    ticks.splice(tLen - 2, 2, max);

    return ticks;

  }
},
```